# PHP var_dump displays string(2) "55" . How to echo this value and assign to a variable?

Tags: php

When I run the code

```
var_dump($data);
```

this is what I get:

```
string(2) "55"
```

How do I echo this out and assign "55" to a variable?

Comment: $data is already a variable, displaying the output is done via echo, print, printf, etc.

Comment: i don't know if i understand your question correclty. But the $data variable already has "55" assigned to itself. The var_dump() function just gives you some information about the format of the variable.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Comment: ^ see the first code example in that link please.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign directly and print directly.

```
 echo $data;
 $var = $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use echo to print the values assigned to the variable.

```
echo($data);
```